# MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem) returns null

Tags: java, android, menu, android-support-library, menuitem

I am trying to get the `View` of the `MenuItem`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    View miView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    if (miView == null) {
        Log.e(X, "mView is null");
    }
}
```

but everytime `miView is null`.

Here's my `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.Foo);
    return true;
}
```

I know that `MenuItemCompat` returns null because the created `Menu` is not a from `support` library, so the `MenuItem` can't be handled by the `MenuItemCompat` class, isn't?

1) I am looking for some method like `onCreateOptionsMenuCompat`, is there any method like that?
2) How can i get ActionView from `MenuItemCompat` class?

and What am i doing wrong ?

PS: my project's **minSdkVersion is 9**

Answer (score 1):

To get an ActionView from a menu item, you will need to set an ActionView on it first. Normal menu items do not come with ActionViews. ActionViews are used when you need to do something extra in your menu (outside of a normal icon and/or text).

Why are you trying to get a View from the menu item? What are you trying to do with your menu item?

Comment: I want to create a `ContextMenu` on `MenuItem` click, so i need the `View`. is there any other option to get the `View` of a `MenuItem`?

Comment: You can manually show a context menu by calling `openContextMenu()` on your Activity. You can call that method in your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. You'll still need to implement the other context menu callbacks (like `onCreateContextMenu`)